# Spring Integration 3.0.1 Restful http-inbound-gateway doesn't convert request body into object

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am trying to use Spring Integration (3.0.1) to implement a RESTful service that supports **both** XML and JSON as request and response formats, using a int-http:inbound-gateway.

My code is based on the Spring integration example (although this does not use the message payload):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/rest-http

Service Activator class:

```
@Service("httpOrderGateway")
public class HttpOrderGateway implements OrderGateway {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(HttpOrderGateway.class);

    @Override
    public Message<CreateOrderResponse> createOrder(Message<CreateOrderRequest> orderRequest) {
        LOGGER.info("Received CreateOrderRequest headers: " + orderRequest.getHeaders());
        LOGGER.info("Received: " + orderRequest.getPayload());

        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(new CreateOrderResponse("Thank you for your order")).build();
    }

}
```

Spring integration XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
       xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http">

    <int:annotation-config />  

    <int:channel id="orderRequestChannel" />
    <int:channel id="orderResponseChannel" />

    <int-http:inbound-gateway id="inboundOrderRequestGateway" 
                              supported-methods="POST"
                              request-channel="orderRequestChannel"
                              reply-channel="orderResponseChannel"
                              view-name="/order"
                              path="/services/order"
                              reply-timeout="50000">
    </int-http:inbound-gateway>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="contentNegotiationManager">
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
                <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />
                <property name="mediaTypes">
                    <map>
                        <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                        <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                    </map>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.anon.order.gateway.json.view.ExtendedMappingJacksonJsonView">
                    <property name="objectMapper" ref="jaxbJacksonObjectMapper" />
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                    <constructor-arg ref="marshaller" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller" contextPath="com.anon.order.gateway.marshalling.model.impl" />

    <int:service-activator id="orderGatewayActivator"
                               input-channel="orderRequestChannel"
                               output-channel="orderResponseChannel"
                               ref="httpOrderGateway" 
                               method="createOrder" 
                               requires-reply="true"
                               send-timeout="60000" />

    <bean id="jaxbJacksonObjectMapper" class="com.anon.order.gateway.json.JaxbJacksonObjectMapper" />

</beans>
```

Currently, the code logs out:

```
Received: <CustomerServiceRequest><CustomerName>Robert Pulson</CustomerName></CustomerServiceRequest>
```

(or the equivalent JSON format), and returns a response in either JSON or XML, depending on the Accept Header, so that part is working.

I have read the following similar question that is based on a previous version of Spring Integration:

[Spring Integration : http:inbound-channel adapter - not getting json object in payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010913/spring-integration-httpinbound-channel-adapter-not-getting-json-object-in-p?rq=1)

But this uses an `inbound-channel-adaptor`, not an `inbound-gateway` as I have.

How do I configure my `inbound-gateway` to use the `marshaller` and `jaxbJacksonObjectMapper` (from the same configuration file) to convert the raw request body into a `CreateOrderRequest` instance for both JSON/XML please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure appropriate `HttpMessageConverter`s and inject them using the `message-converters` attribute.

See also the `merge-with-default-converters` attribute.

See `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` (jackson 2), `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` (jackson 1.x) and `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter`.

Also, JAXB and Json message converters are automatically used by default if they are on the classpath. You may be able to just set the `request-payload-type` on the gateway if conversion doesn't need anything special.

See the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#http-inbound) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but none of the above have made any difference. The inbound-gateway does not have an expected-type attribute. Are there any plans to update the rest-http example in GIT with a POST example with the body being converted?

Comment: Sorry - typo, the attribute is `request-payload-type`.

Comment: I just pushed a commit to my branch showing `JSON->Map` by just adding the `request-payload-type`. https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-integration-samples/commit/a5b46a4a41d4ab820015adbea9ceac3d70b663ea

Comment: That solved it - I appreciate your help, thanks alot. For some reason the request-payload-type wasn't auto completing in the IDE so I didn't know I could use that.